# narrowing and widening column witdh dynamically for INTERACTIVE GRID in apex 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1

I couldn't succeed to set dynamically column witdh for INTERACTIVE GRID in apex 19.1 for smaller screen or mobil devices. could you please help me? I need them to be narrowing and widening otomatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem this way:

1st step: select grid region and set Advanced -> Custom Attributes -> style='width : 100%;'

2nd step: For each column set Advanced -> Custom Attributes -> style='width : auto;'

That's all!